# How to add custom link in Yii 2 validation error message?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components, yii2-advanced-app

I would like to add custom link in Yii 2 model based validation message.

I am using following code block at the moment-

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    ['email', 'required'],
    ['email', 'email'],
    ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 
                        'message' =>   'Email address has already been taken.'],
  ];
}
```

I want this message to display like following-

"Email address is taken. **Already registered?** Then log-in ***here***."

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 'message' =>   'Email address has already been taken. Already registered? Then log-in '.HTML::a('here.', $url)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comment, you need to add link in to your `message` parameter, and also to prevent link from being encoded you need to set *encode* parameter to *false*.

```
$form->field($model, 'email', ['errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block' ,'encode' => false]])->textInput()
```